# GeoDirectory REST API OAuth 1.0a which credentials?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

In WordPress using GeoDirectory REST API to create a listing (POST HTTP request).

I'm using OAuth 1.0a, which I guess is the proper one, but I don't know how to generate the signature and other params they require.

There is no practical example of how to do it, especially how to generate the request signature (oauth_signature) and which nonce to put in.

Comment: The general process of signing a request in OAuth 1 is described f.e. here, https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have a look at this one.